# how to copy a value from an url into the html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy a value from the url into the html-code.

i.e:

when my url is

```
www.website.com/page?destination=other_page
```

i want to copy everything from the "?" to the action of form:

```
<form action="/user/register/" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

should become:

```
<form action="/user/register/?destination=other_page" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can get the url using window.location

Comment: @slashsharp that wont work if the post url is different from the current page

Comment: @Brian yes it can, there's a lot of other methods in window.location

Comment: @slashsharp right, I misunderstood. `location.search` to be precise, like in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the entire querystring using `window.location.search`. You can then append that to the current `action` attribute using `attr()`, like this:

```
$('form').attr('action', function(i, a) {
  return a + window.location.search;
});
```

Comment: in addition to @Rory answer, i would suggest to look up [XSS attack](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/?utm_source=tuicool) since your code seams to be very vulnerable to it.